# Get the url parameters on tcp connection stage

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to identify the clients when they try to connect to my tcp server so i can reject or accept the connection.But I find it hard to find the answers to my problem or if it even possible to achieve this before allowing the client to connect first.

I have an idea. If the clients connects to: `tcp://127.0.0.1:8080?auth=34356`

we can check the auth parameter to identify the clients. The problem i don't know how to achieve this.

I'm using nodejs as tcp server like this:

```
var netlib = require('net');

var server = netlib.createServer(function(socket) {

});


 server.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log('CONNECTED SOCKET DATA', socket.address());
    console.log('CONNECTED LOCAL, %s:%s', socket.localAddress, socket.localPort);
    console.log('CONNECTED %s:%s', socket.remoteAddress, socket.remotePort);

  });


server.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
```

Can someone please show me how to get the url parameter and value?

Comment: What is `tcp://127.0.0.1:8080?auth=34356`?  It sort of looks like an HTTP URL but isn't.  How would you connect to this server in such a way?  TCP doesn't have any concept of query parameters.

Comment: I have seen redis accept query parameters. But i'm sure you are correct. How can i else pass data on connection stage?

Comment: You can't.  TCP doesn't have such a concept.  You'll need to decide on a protocol which will probably be used for the entire session.  Once you decide on such a protocol, the client will simply send its authentication data as the first message.  If the server doesn't receive valid authentication data, it will close the connection.

Comment: You should put your answer down below so i can choose it. Your answer give me peace in my mind, because you explain that there is nothing wrong with the code, but tcp just don't work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP doesn't have a concept of authentication during connection establishment. You'll need to decide on a protocol which will probably be used for the entire session. Once you decide on such a protocol, the client will simply send its authentication data as the first message. If the server doesn't receive valid authentication data, it will close the connection.